# How to connect ufront with sqlite?

Tags: haxe, ufront

Can I use ufront with sqlite3? How can i do so?

Need to put some words here so stackoverflow accepts my question, summon Jason Oneil, or my question will never be online, palease o great stack overflow, accept my question.

Comment: I still haven't tried ufront, but you can probably use your own database driver independently from ufront. I think that ufront has an extension to Spod (`sys.db.*`), so you should be able to use it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

Before `ufrontApplication.executeRequest()`:

```
Manager.cnx = sys.db.Sqlite.open("test.db");
```

Haven't tested features thoroughly, but the `hello-world` app seems to work fine now.